# Find Order of a Differential Equation (ODE or PDE)

Tags: differential-equations, order

In Mathematica, I need a code in order to find the order of ODEs and PDEs.

Here are some examples using different notations:

- For fifth-order ODE:

`D[u[t], {t,5}]-D[u[t], {t,3}] u[t] +D[u[t],t] +Cot[t]==0`

- For Second-order PDE:

`D[u[x,t], x] + u[x,t] +D[u[x,t], x,t] - Sin[t]==0`

- For Third-order PDE using `Derivative` :

`Derivative[1, 1, 1 ][f][x, y, t ] == Exp[x y t]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following function:

```
    Clear[findOrder];

    findOrder[equation_] := Module[{pos},
  pos = Position[equation, Derivative[n___][_][___]];
  Map[Total, 
    equation[[Sequence @@ #]] & /@ pos /. 
     Derivative[n__][x_][y___] -> {n}] // Max
  ]
```

Let us try it on your equations:

```
eq1 = D[u[t], {t, 5}] - D[u[t], {t, 3}] u[t] + D[u[t], t] + Cot[t] == 0
findOrder[eq]

(*  5  *)
```

Then

```
    eq2 = D[u[x, t], x] + u[x, t] + D[u[x, t], x, t] - Sin[t] == 0
    findOrder[eq2]

(* 2 *)
```

and

```
eq3 = Derivative[1, 1, 1][f][x, y, t] == Exp[x y t]
findOrder[eq3]

(*  3  *)
```

Have fun!

Comment: It should be: `findOrder[eq1]` :)

Comment: @Mariusz Iwaniuk Yes, you are right, of course. I initially named it eq, and later changed it to eq1 to make coherent notations.